# gridview scrolling doesn't render correctly (appropriate)

Tags: android, android-gridview, custom-adapter

I have a strange problem with android gridview. I implement a custom adapter for my gridview and load data from a Rest API. according to a boolean flag from the server the design of gridview change. the gridview has an onScrollListener which fetch more data from api and reset adapter. the problem is when I scroll too much (for example 5 times more loading) the result becomes wrong, I mean the rendered result is not what I am expecting. the strange part is when I come back and scroll up, the other results missing some part (for example the discountbox part gone).

I post my custom adapter class code :

```
public class GridItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private Context mContext;
List<SimpleItem> SimpleItems;

public GridItemAdapter(Context mcontext, List<SimpleItem> SimpleItems) {
    this.mContext = mcontext;
    this.SimpleItems = SimpleItems;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return SimpleItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return SimpleItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public void addItems(List<SimpleItem> SimpleItems) {
    this.SimpleItems.addAll(SimpleItems);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
    }
    SimpleItem item = SimpleItems.get(position);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(item.getTitle());
    TextView territory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.territory);
    territory.setText(item.getTitle());
    ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    Picasso.with(mContext)
            .load(item.getThumbnail())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.noimage)
            .into(thumbnail);
    TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
    price.setText(item.getPrice());
    if (item.getHasDiscount()) {
        TextView discount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discount);
        discount.setText(item.getDiscount());
    } else {
        LinearLayout discountbox = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discountbox);
        price.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
        discountbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

}

clarifying example : I expect to have discountbox visible in an item, but when scrolling there isn't and discountbox doesn't appear. Or when it is rendered correctly at first, when I scroll down more and come back it disappear :(

I will be very thankful if anybody help me. I somehow suspicious about gridview recycling but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this change to the code and see if it solves the issue, it is just calling to set the discountbox visible

```
          if (item.getHasDiscount()) {
              TextView discount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discount);
              discountbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              discount.setText(item.getDiscount());
          } else {
              LinearLayout discountbox = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discountbox);
              price.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
              discountbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          }
```